# Global style does not apply

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

this is my C# code

```
MainWindow.Content = new UserControl();
```

after MainWindow navigate to a new UserControl, global style
defined in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
   </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

does not apply on it
but in visual studio, constructor show that the UserControl applied that style by changing his background
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no Background value set on the UserControl itself?
To find the actual value of a Dependency Property like UserControl.Background WPF uses a set order. If you set the Background property directly the style will not overide it (see [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx)).